# React native Model popup style Issue

Tags: react-native

I  make check box list on Model Pop up by using react native multiple select
checkbox list listed but  it take full screen height
i am not able to fix this issue
please Any body help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Outer Element would be a modal, then make a view of a specific height inside that modal,

Example

```
<Modal transparent={true}
                    visible={this.state.showDialog}
                    animationType='fade'>
                    <View style={{opacity:.5, backgroundColor:'black',flex:1}}/>
                    <View 
                   
                    style={{position:'absolute',padding:16,top:0,bottom:0,left:0,right:0
                    ,justifyContent:'center',alignContent:"center",
                    alignItems:'center'}}>
                           <View style={{backgroundColor:’red’,padding:16,borderRadius:5,
                            width:'60%',height:'10%',alignContent:'center',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:14,alignSelf:'center',textAlign:'center'}}>
                                    Sorry!!
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={{marginTop:5,fontSize:12,alignSelf:'center',textAlign:'center',color:’black’}}>
                                    {this.props.errorMessage}
                            </Text>
                            <Button title='close'
                            onPress={()=>this.setState({showDialog:false})}/>
                           </View>
                    </View>
                    </Modal>
```